# Is the harmonic mean the maximum likelihood estimator for some common continous distribution's parameter?

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, mean, harmonic-mean

If $y$ is a vector of continuous data the arithmetic mean is the maximum likelihood estimator for $\mu$ when assuming $y \sim \text{Normal}(\mu,\sigma)$ (not uniquely, of course). The geometric mean is the maximum likelihood estimator of $\mu$ when assuming $y \sim \text{Log-Normal}(\mu,\sigma)$. **Similarly, is the harmonic mean the maximum likelihood estimator for a parameter of some common distribution?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This will happen for the *recirpocal* of a random variable following an Exponential distribution.**

Let $X$ follow an Exponential distribution with probability density function

$$f_X(x) = \alpha e^{-\alpha x}$$

Consider $$ Y = \frac 1{X} \Rightarrow X = 1/Y \Rightarrow \frac{\partial X}{\partial Y} = -Y^{-2}$$

Then

$$f_Y(y) = \left|\frac{\partial X}{\partial Y}\right|\cdot  f_X(1/y)= \alpha y^{-2}e^{-\alpha/y},\;\;  y\in (0,\infty)$$

The log-likelihood of a sample of $n$ observations will be

$$\ln L = n\ln\alpha -2\sum_{i=1}^n\ln y_i -\alpha \sum_{i=1}^n(1/y_i)$$

and

$$\frac{\partial \ln L}{\partial \alpha} = \frac n{\alpha}-\sum_{i=1}^n(1/y_i) = 0 \Rightarrow \hat \alpha_{ML} = \frac n{\sum_{i=1}^n(1/y_i)}$$

which is the harmonic mean of the $y$'s.

Comment: that's silly, you could have found the well known estimator for x (n/sum(x)) and just plug in x=1/y

Comment: @HananShteingart  1) "Well known" to whom? To the millions of visitors in this site? 2) Mathematical details are like etymology of a word: they help understand more securely and permanently what is going on.